# django admin: Adding a textarea and a button that invokes a function

Tags: django, django-admin

On the main admin screen I want a link that when clicked would bring up a page with a textarea along with a button that when clicked will invoke a python function. That function would return data that would be displayed on the page below the textarea.

If this were a regular page that was part of my app I could easily do this, but I'm not sure how to integrate something like this into my admin page. Everything thing in admin seems to be tied to a model, and this is not. Do I have to create a dummy model for this? Let's say I do create a dummy model, then how do I get django to display my custom template for this?

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this django app: https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus to add links at the bottom of the list of models without adding a dummy once.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This looks very useful, but in this case I decided to go with the dummy table. I will keep the link to admin plus for future references.